# z-index of some sorts and keeping things painted in Applet

Tags: java, applet

I am making a java applet using awt. I know it's old but our professor is requiring us to use it so please bear with it. My problem is with the layering of images. As of right now, to layer images on top of another, I have to display each Image I have that I want to be on top of another first before displaying the others. This makes things quite complicated and messy. Is there a way (media tracker or something) to make it so that an image *image 1* always is on top of another image *image 2*?

Also, the program I'm making is a dungeon-crawler type game. The screen is filled up by a 5x5 area block of images of 32 px each. Something like:

```
[W][W][ ][ ][W]
[W][ ][ ][ ][W]
[W][W][W][ ][ ]
[ ][W][ ][ ][ ]
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
```

Where [W] are wall images and [ ] are path images. The thing is, I want this set of images to always display, and only repaint the character as he moves through the images. Is there a way so that these images will not be cleared when repaint is called?

Here's my code:

```
public class GUI extends Applet implements KeyListener {
    int imageSize = 32;
    int dimensions = imageSize*5; //makes the display 5x5
    Image pathImage, wallImage, playerImage;
    MediaTracker mt;

    public void init() {
        this.setSize(dimensions, dimensions);
        mt = new MediaTracker();
        pathImage = getImage(getCodeBase(), "path.gif"); //all the images are stills
        wallImage = getImage(getCodeBase(), "wall.gif");
        playerImage = getImage(getCodeBase(), "player.gif");
        mt.addImage(pathImage, 0);
        mt.addImage(wallImage, 1);
        mt.addImage(playerImage, 2);
        addKeyListener(this);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        try {
            tracker.waitForAll();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        }

//this first one prints the first three layers from the top of the 5x5 display
 int x = 0;
            int y = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                        switch(Global.currentMap.getTileMap(player.getXCoordinate() + j - 2,                  

  player.getYCoordinate() + i - 2).getImageID()) {
                        case "path":
                            g.drawImage(pathImage, x, y, imageSize, imageSize, this);
                            break;
                        case "wall":
                            g.drawImage(wallImage, x, y - imageSize/2, imageSize, imageSize*3/2,   
this);
                            break;
                    }
                    x += imageSize;
                }
                y += imageSize;
                x = 0;
            }

            //this one draws the player so that it's on top of the top 3 layers
            g.drawImage(bird[face], imageSize*2, imageSize, imageSize, imageSize*2, this);

            //this one draws the last two layers so they're on top of the player
            for(int i = 3; i < 5; i++) {
                for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                    switch(Global.currentMap.getTileMap(player.getXCoordinate() + j - 2,                 
player.getYCoordinate() + i - 2).getImageID()) {
                        case "wall":
                            g.drawImage(wallImage, x, y - imageSize/2, imageSize, imageSize*3/2,         

this);
                            break;
                        case "path":
                            g.drawImage(pathImage, x, y, imageSize, imageSize, this);
                            break;
                    }
                    x += imageSize;
                }
                y += imageSize;
                x = 0;
            }
    }
```

The above code isn't the same code. But I hope it illustrates my point wherein I have to layer the images.

Here is a sample output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZG0vu.jpg

Thanks.

Comment: your question is too broad and this website is not right place for such a question :)

Comment: I'm sorry! I accidentally pressed enter when typing out the tags LOL. It's fixed now. :)

Comment: It is ok. No need to be sorry. Just please post up some code what you have done so far thank you :)